# How to use my personal keyboard layout?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I read few topic about customizing personal keyboard layout or creating new one. I create a BALOCHI language keyboard layout for my self. following is the contet of "blc" file in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ which I created:

```
default
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys 
xkb_symbols "blc" {

name[Group1]= "Baloc (blc)";

// Alphanumeric section
key <TLDE> {    [         ŕ,    Ř       ]   };
key <AE01> {    [     1,    exclam      ]   };
key <AE02> {    [     2,    at      ]   };
key <AE03> {    [     3,    semicolon   ]   };
key <AE04> {    [     4,    colon       ]   };
key <AE05> {    [     5,    percent     ]   };
key <AE06> {    [     6,    apostrophe  ]   };
key <AE07> {    [     7,    quotedbl    ]   };
key <AE08> {    [     8,    asterisk    ]   };
key <AE09> {    [     9,    parenleft   ]   };
key <AE10> {    [     0,    parenright  ]   };
key <AE11> {    [     minus,    underscore  ]   };
key <AE12> {    [     equal,    plus        ]   };

key <AD01> {    [     q,    Q       ]   };
key <AD02> {    [     w,    W       ]   };
key <AD03> {    [     e,    E       ]   };
key <AD04> {    [     r,    R       ]   };
key <AD05> {    [     t,    T       ]   };
key <AD06> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
key <AD07> {    [     u,    U       ]   };
key <AD08> {    [     i,    I       ]   };
key <AD09> {    [     o,    O       ]   };
key <AD10> {    [     p,    P       ]   };
key <AD11> {    [     è,    È       ]   };
key <AD12> {    [     ù,    Ù       ]   };

key <AC01> {    [     a,    A       ]   };
key <AC02> {    [     s,    S       ]   };
key <AC03> {    [     d,    D       ]   };
key <AC04> {    [     f,    F       ]   };
key <AC05> {    [     g,    G       ]   };
key <AC06> {    [     h,    H       ]   };
key <AC07> {    [     j,    J       ]   };
key <AC08> {    [     k,    K       ]   };
key <AC09> {    [     l,    L       ]   };
key <AC10> {    [     à,    À       ]   };
key <AC11> {    [     ś,    Ś       ]   };

key <AB01> {    [     z,    Z       ]   };
key <AB02> {    [     x,    X       ]   };
key <AB03> {    [     c,    C       ]   };
key <AB04> {    [     v,    V       ]   };
key <AB05> {    [     b,    B       ]   };
key <AB06> {    [     n,    N       ]   };
key <AB07> {    [     m,    M       ]   };
key <AB08> {    [         ť,    Ť       ]   };
key <AB09> {    [         ď,    Ď       ]   };
key <AB10> {    [         ž,    Ž       ]   };

key <BKSL> {    [  question,         slash  ]   };
// End alphanumeric section
};
```

I saved that file and restart my laptop but I can not find my keybord layout in keyboard layout setting to use it?
What is wrong? plz

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new entry for `blc` in  `evdev.xml` and `evdev.lst` files from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules` directory.

> Adding a new layout requires that you also add the file to `rules/evdev.xml`. If you use other X11 wms you may want to give your layout to the rest of the xorg system. You can do this by adding the file to the `symbols` directory, and adding a line for the file in `rules/evdev.lst` under the `! layout` section.

Source: [Howto: Custom keyboard layout definitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions)